# Creating a subdomain network in a subdomain

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I've installed Wordpress on subdomain.domain.com.

I've enabled the Wordpress Network on this installation, choosing a subdomain install.

I've created a wildcard subdomain in cpanel, which is *.subdomain(.domain.com), which points to /public_html/subdomain

I've created a site: site.subdomain.domain.com, but I cannot visit the dashboard of this site, nor does it show under the My Sites dropdown menu after creating it - I get an ISP Site Not Found page.

Is this situation not workable: creating a subdomain network in a subdomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the ‘wildcard’ DNS entry was not in the zonefile for *.subdomain.

Tech Support fixed this for me, and it is up and running, except for the fact that the new website is still not listed under the Sites dropdown menu.

Answer (score 2):

The site not being listed under My sites has happened to me loads. Go to Network Admin > Sites and you should see you site. The username is more than likely, not yours, Simply go into the user editor section add your self as an admin and delete the default user. This should make it appear under you My Sites.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/networks-for-wordpress/), maybe its your solution. Create multiple networks in the netowrk of MU.

Comment: I think that is essentially Networks+Domain Mapping - if so, that does not solve the problem unfortunately.